# Using ISNUMBER and SEARCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use the formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("180",A1,0),1,0)` but for some reason it isn't working.  I tried removing the quotes and the same problem occurred, I see entries (e.g. "it is 180 degrees") that contain '180' but it doesn't catch them.  Does SEARCH not work with numbers?

Comment: I couldn't find how search manage numbers, but probably don't find in them, if you want your formula working also with numeric only try to use: `""&A1` instead of just `A1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parens and should start with **1**:

**=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(180,A1,1)),1,0)**

[image]

Works fine without the 'double quotes'